# React Flux: How do I auto-sort stored array when a new item is added?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm trying to figure out the best way of updating a stored array when a new item is added to it.

Right now I'm sorting it with the code below (sortMissions() is called in the AppDispatcher.register code), but it feels inefficient since the array will be sorted every time one of my switch cases is called, even if it's irrelevant to the _missions array (e.g. if _incomplete_missions changes, I'll still be sorting _missions).

```
//MissionStore.js
// Define initial data points
var _missions = [], _incomplete_missions = [];

// Add a mission to _missions
function addMission(mission){
    _missions.push(mission);
}

// Sort _missions as desired
function sortMissions(){
    _missions = _(_missions).chain().sortBy('name').sortBy('points').value();
}

...

var MissionStore = _.extend({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    ...
    // Return Mission data
    getMissions: function() {
        return _missions;
    },
    // emit change event
    emitChange: function() {
        this.emit('change');
    },

    // add change listener
    addChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.on('change', callback);
    },

    // remove change listener
    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.removeListener('change', callback);
    }
});

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action;
    var text;

    switch(action.actionType) {

        case MissionActionConstants.MISSION_SAVE:
            addMission(action.mission);
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

    sortMissions();
    MissionStore.emitChange();

    return true;
});
```

I thought about just sorting _missions in MissionStore.getMissions() and no where else, but that will result in sorting it every time getMissions() called, whether anything changed or not.

I also thought about inserting sortMissions() in every dispatcher case that _missions would change, but that seems like I'm duplicating myself.

Ideally I'd like to subscribe to changes just on the _missions array (from within the same store) and sort _missions only when it changes, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Thanks!

Comment: If the data should always be in a sorted state, why not sort it when you add a mission?

Comment: I haven't coded it out yet, but the missions are editable (e.g. the point values or names can change) & I'm planning to add alternative sorting methods later. Once I've added both those options in, i'd need to be calling sortMissions() on editMission & editSortMethod which would have me repeating myself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do the sorting in the controller-view, not in the store.

This way, you maintain only one collection of missions, and this could be immutable data.  I recommend [ImmutableJS](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for that.

Then, if `MissionsStore.getMissions() !== this.state.missions`, you do the sort and then pass the sorted collection to `this.setState()`.

Otherwise, I think you're looking at maintaining a separate cached collection for every type of sort, which seems like a lot to maintain.  But it's certainly a viable alternative.

Comment: That seems like it might work. I guess I'd either have to a) fire an action after sorting in my view-controller to update the store (for comparing later changes) or b) keep two arrays in my controller-view, one sorted and one unsorted for comparing with MissionStore.getMissions(). Option a) seems like the better alternative of those two, but it feels kind of weird to do an extra action-dispatch-store circuit when all the info was available before.